# TFS: How to maintain project references when branching

Tags: tfs, branch

Our Visual Studio 2010 Solution includes six projects.  One of the six is the main application and the remaining five are class libraries that are configured as Project References in the main application. Our TFS Source Control structure is as follows:

- TeamProject\ClassLibries\Class1
- TeamProject\ClassLibries\Class2
  .
  .
- TeamProject\WindowsApps\Application1

I need to create a Branch of Application1 so I have this:

- TeamProject\WindowsApps\Application1
- TeamProject\WindowsApps\Application1-NewFeature

My question is, when I create the Branch for Application1, do I also need to create Branches for the five Project References whether they get updated with the new feature or not?  If I do, do I need to manually update the Project References so Application1-NewFeature knows to reference Class1-NewFeature instead of just Class1?  When I merge the new feature back into the main branch, do I need to update the Project References all over again?  Branching is totally new to me and I'm afraid I'll have a mess of Branches and Project References that gets out of control.  What is "Best Practice" for this scenario?

Comment: I believe your question is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720661/tfs-2010-branch-across-team-projects-best-practices

Comment: @dash: that's a different question.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I kind of agree and disagree; the answer to the OP's post is yes, you should  branch in all of the other projects too if you *expect* to update them (which I appreciate *is* painful in TFS) but the other question covers best practice in this area. IMO of course, which means that no one else has to vote for close! If the OP isn't going to update the other projects, then there isn't really a need to. Should really have asked for clarification, I suppose.

Comment: When you add your new feature to Application-1, is this the *only* code that will change? The purpose of branching is really to isolate/separate changes from different versions of the code so if only Application1 is going to change then you don't need to branch the other projects. If you expect that changes in the class libraries will be needed as well, then you should branch, and the answer in the link above gives some guidance on what people regard as best practice.

Comment: At least one of the other projects will be updated but not all so I suppose only those projects that will be changed needs to be branched.  I'll try to follow the other's Best Practices but I don't think I can modify the way our TFS folders are structured.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: If it's any solace, we've done the same thing lots. It's a shame that TFS is so atomic at the project level (which makes branching in several projects a real chore). Understandable if you take the point of view that they really wanted all of a projects files to live in the same project folder, though, in my experience, your scenario is more common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it best, in effect, to branch the entire *solution* or system of solutions. It doesn't *duplicate* files, so it's not a big deal to have projects in your branch that you're not going to change.

Ironically, one rule of thumb that I use is that anything referenced via project references should be branched together.